# Return valueOf object when called as a function

Tags: javascript, class, date, object, oop

I'm creating a specific class in which I'd like to return the value of the class when it is called standalone, rather than returning the entire class model.

I've seen other people ask similar questions and seen recommended solutions using the `valueOf` and `toString` methods, but those methods both require writing the class as a string somewhere or calling it in some form of computation. I'd like my class to work in such a way where when I call the class, even in a simple console log by itself, it returns its value, without any other details about the other properties and methods available. I'm sure some people will say this is counterintuitive and probably not a good idea, but this is my ideal use case, and this is exactly how the `Date()` object works, so I feel this must be possible somehow.

When you create a new instance of the `Date` object, there are plenty of methods available (e.g. `getMonth(), getFullYear(), setTime(), toJSON(), toDateString(), etc.`), but if you just call an instance of the date object without any methods or properties specified, it appears to return the date, unless this is just the browser console assisting developers by displaying some form of the stringified date, so they don't need to call `.toString()` to get the string value by default.

```js
const now = new Date();

console.log(now);
// -> "2021-04-26T14:44:30.466Z"

console.log(now.toString());
// -> Mon Apr 26 2021 10:44:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(now.valueOf());
// -> 1619448336448
```

Would returning a "default" property like this be possible? Please keep in mind, I have already read similar questions here on StackOverflow and really scoured the platform and not seen any that answer this questions specifically.

Comment: `.toString()` and `.valueOf()` are the two choices you have.

Comment: @Pointy that's what I've seen thus far, but then why does the `Date` object appear to get special treatment in this regard?

Comment: Because the Date prototype has `.toString()` and `.valueOf()` methods, plus the browser consoles do all sorts of weird things.

Comment: That was my main question. My class uses both the `.toString()` and `.valueOf()` methods but when I log them to my console in an array, I get an array full of objects. I guess I can just map the array to their values.

Comment: The console is designed to be helpful, but its behavior is not defined by any spec and it can be really confusing. If you want to log a simple value, call either `.toString()` or `.valueOf()` explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. All objects inherit a `.toString()` and `.valueOf()` property and both work out of the box, although they may not return the string or value that you would like. If that's the case, simply override those properties to return whatever you need. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think the question is "How can I make `console.log(myObject)` do what I want?" and the answer is that you pretty much can't.

Comment: @Pointy But, if you override `.toString()` and/or `.valueOf()`, you can, can't you?

Comment: @ScottMarcus well that depends on how the console code decides to work. Usually if you `console.log(someObject)` you get more or less the same output as `console.dir()` but it's up to the particular browser or Node or whatever. Of course the argument is just a JavaScript expression so `console.log("Value: " + myObject)` will indeed call `.toString()`

Comment: @Pointy I think I better understand the reason for this issue now and see that the `Date` isn't getting special treatment here so much as it is the browser displaying the date object differently when console logged without a method. You've effectively answered my question. Can you please submit your response as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line is that you don't have much control over what the `console` API does. When you hand it an object, in order to be helpful it will give you the object contents to explore. Of course the console code is familiar with native JavaScript types, so it might do something special with things like Date instances because, again, it's trying to be helpful. (That "helpfulness" causes a lot of confusion and there are hundreds if not thousands of questions here that can be traced to people not understanding what the console is trying to do.)

So you can add `.toString()` and `.valueOf()` methods to your classes, and take advantage of them for debugging etc. by either calling the methods explicitly or using them implicitly, as in:

```
console.log("Current status: " + myObject);
```

The `+` concatenation operator will implicitly call the `.toString()` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Also, do you know if there is any similar method like these that work for destructuring? For example, it would work great for my specific use-case if I could destructure `{ Class1, Class2 }` to return an object like this `{ Class1: Class1.value, Class2.value }`

Comment: Worth noting that whether `+` acts as concatenation, addition or unary + depends on the types of the values in the expression, e.g. `+ date` returns a number, `3 + date` returns a string. ;-)